# How do I compare two images and transform them to match?

Tags: flutter, dart, image-processing, image-manipulation, image-recognition

I am taking two similar images and putting one on top of the other as semi transparent overlay.
What I'm trying to achieve now is to compare the difference between them and transform (scale, crop, move and rotate) the image on top so it matches the image underneath as good as it can.

Here is a visual representation:

[image: Two separate images]

[image: Mismatching when on top]

I'm trying to achieve this in Flutter, but other approaches to a solution help aswell.

Edit: I already made this with a Stack widget I can transform the image on top by panning. But I am looking for a way to make this thing automated by analyzing the images.

Comment: You could us a stack widget and add opacity in image widget

Comment: Thanks, thats how i made these screenshot. What I'm trying to achieve is to make this thing automated.

Comment: You could make a screen with an image picker and pass the values to the next screen containing your already existent image widget with opacity and stack. Does that work for you?

Comment: If you want we can have a meeting and go trough the implementation together